# Variable arguments to a shell script

Tags: bash

I would like  to have my script accepting variable arguments. How do I check for them individually?

For example

```
./myscript arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4

 or 

./myscript arg4 arg2 arg3
```

The arguments can be any number and in any order. I would like to check if arg4 string is present or not irrespective of the argument numbers.

How do I do that?

Thanks,

Comment: Are these args fixed strings (similar to `--help`, `--version`, etc.) or are they "anything"?

Comment: Duplicate, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255898/how-to-iterate-over-arguments-in-bash-script, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528292/passing-multiple-arguments-to-a-unix-shell-script

Comment: Yeah. I'm passing few flags as arguments to the script not necessarily in fixed numbers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The safest way — the way that handles all possibilities of whitespace in arguments, and so on — is to write an explicit loop:

```
arg4_is_an_argument=''
for arg in "$@" ; do
    if [[ "$arg" = 'arg4' ]] ; then
        arg4_is_an_argument=1
    fi
done
if [[ "$arg4_is_an_argument" ]] ; then
    : the argument was present
else
    : the argument was not present
fi
```

If you're certain your arguments won't contain spaces — or at least, if you're not particularly worried about that case — then you can shorten that to:

```
if [[ " $* " == *' arg4 '* ]] ; fi
    : the argument was almost certainly present
else
    : the argument was not present
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

This is playing fast and loose with the typical interpretation of command line "arguments", but I start most of my bash scripts with the following, as an easy way to add `--help` support:

```
if [[ "$@" =~ --help ]]; then
  echo 'So, lemme tell you how to work this here script...'
  exit
fi
```

The main drawback is that this will also be triggered by arguments like `request--help.log`, `--no--help`, etc. (not just `--help`, which might be a requirement for your solution).

**To apply this method in your case, you would write something like:**

```
[[ "$@" =~ arg4 ]] && echo "Ahoy, arg4 sighted!"
```

*Bonus!* If your script requires at least one command line argument, you can similarly trigger a help message when no arguments are supplied:

```
if [[ "${@---help}" =~ --help ]]; then
  echo 'Ok first yer gonna need to find a file...'
  exit 1
fi
```

which uses the empty-variable-substitution syntax `${VAR-default}` to hallucinate a `--help` argument if absolutely no arguments were given.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this can help.

```
#!/bin/bash
# this is myscript.sh

[ `echo $* | grep arg4` ] && echo true || echo false
```